# GDAL.Rasterize in Python options not working

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I got the following command that works fine:

> gdal_rasterize -l type -a TOT_P_2018 -tr 1000.0 1000.0 -a_nodata -1.0
> -te -2825000.0 -3077000.0 10028000.0 5418000.0 -ot Int32 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9
> grid_1km_surf.gpkg output.tif

How do I convert it to Python code? This is my code:

```
vector = ogr.Open("grid_1km_surf.gpkg")
vlayer = vector.GetLayer()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = vlayer.GetExtent()
gdal.Rasterize("output.tif", vector_file, xRes=tr, yRes=tr,
               outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax],
               outputType=gdal.GDT_Int32,
               options=['COMPRESS=DEFLATE', 'ATTRIBUTE=TOT_P_2018'])
```

Got stuck on two things:

1. xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax are all zero (QGiS somehow knows it)
2. I am getting an error: `ERROR 6: Too many command options 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE'`

Could someone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe the answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417338/how-to-rasterize-polygons-using-gdal-commands-in-python is useful.

Comment: Could be but still can't set value by attribute, the same problem even when I will move "COMPRESS" to creationOptions - `ERROR 6: Too many command options 'ATTRIBUTE=TOT_P_2018'`

Comment: Have you had a look at [gdal.RasterizeOption](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.RasterizeOptions) in the documents? Maybe set the options with gdal.RasterizeOptions() and then assign it to `options=` in the gdal.Rasterize() function.

Comment: I tried but it gave exactly the same result, but maybe did it wrong way, will try your answer asap, thanx

Answer (score 2):

Using [gdal.RasterizeOption](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.RasterizeOptions) to set the options for `gdal.Rasterize()` usually works.

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

vector_file = "grid_1km_surf.gpkg"

out = "output.tif"
vector = ogr.Open(vector_file)
vlayer = vector.GetLayer()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = vlayer.GetExtent()
print(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# Set the options for gdal.Rasterize() with gdal.RasterizeOptions()
options = gdal.RasterizeOptions(creationOptions=['COMPRESS=DEFLATE'], outputType=gdal.GDT_Int32, outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], xRes=10, yRes=10, targetAlignedPixels=True, attribute=None) # Replace None with your attribute value 

gdal.Rasterize(out, vector_file, options=options)
```